# Do adapters exist for old lenses to Canon's DSLR mount?

Tags: lens, canon, lens-adapter

I currently have a Canon 20D and happened to find a few old lenses.

Are there any adapters that can work for these lenses? I unfortunately haven't been able to find anything.

The old lenses I have are:
* Tokina SZ-X 352 35-200mm F4-5.6
* Minolta MD Rokkor-X 1:1.4 f = 50mm
* Sigma 35-70mm 1:2.8~4

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the mount, and on whether you can accept an optical element in the adapter.

Canon's EF mount has a very short register, which means a lot of lenses for other mounts can be adapted simply with an adapter that moves the lens a few millimeters away from the mount. However, with other mounts you need to get a lens element to achieve infinity focus. This element can affect optical performance.

The lenses that can be used with an adapter without an optical element include, but is not limited to:

- Nikon F mount
- Olympus OM
- Leica R mount
- Contax/Yashica
- M42 screwmount

Lenses that require an optical adapter include, but are not limited to:

- Canon FD mount (old Canon mount before EF)
- Minolta MD

Unless a lens is very unusual, or you're strapped for cash, it's often better to get a lens that doesn't require an optical adapter, as the choices are large for the Canon EF system.

Comment: Pentax K mount is also available with a not-so-cheap [piece of metal](http://cgi.ebay.com/Pentax-K-Mount-Lens-Canon-EOS-EF-50D-500D-450D-5D-II-/270758154880?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item3f0a719280).

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the Tokina, definitely the Minolta, and the Sigma depends on what mount you have.

Check out http://www.srb-griturn.com/other-lenses-on-canon-eos-cameras-334-c.asp

They're based in Britain but they ship to the States if you're there.

Comment: Awesome I'll definitely have a look around and see if I can find some that work! Thanks again